# How to wireup a class that doesn't have an interface

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have a class that just has public properties of services that are already wired up in Windsor.

How can I register this class?

I only know this pattern:

```
 container.Register(Component.For(typeof (IRepository<>))
                    .ImplementedBy(typeof (Repository<>)));
```

But this class doesn't have an interface, it is the implementation.  I am only looking to set this up so the properties are preconfigured when I instantiate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(Repository<>)));
```

or for closed types:

```
container.Register(Component.For<MyConcreteType>());
```